# Sending log messages to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am analyzing the feasibility to send messages from Log4j to kafka topic. In my application kafka brokered is secured using SASL . Do I need to pass JVM parameter 
as below to send messages to kafka topic or is there any other configuration required ?

**Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_client_jaas.conf**

Comment: no, that's it.  SASL_PLAINTEXT or SASL_SSL ?

Comment: @QuentinGeff . It is SASLPLAINTEXT